# finding matching consecutive rows in r

Tags: r, rows, matching

Is there a one-line solution possible for this example?

```
df = data.frame('First' = c('T','T','V','V','A','E'),'Last' = c(rep('Ng',3),'Smith','Wolf','Wolf'))
matches = (df$First[-1] == df$First)
which(matches == 'TRUE')
# [1] 1 3
```

I want the indeces, but would rather not use a temporary variable.

Comment: Do you need `which(df$First[-1] == df$First)` ?

Comment: yes.  beautiful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the `rleid` function from `data.table` in combination with `diff`, like this:

```
which(diff(rleid(df$First)) == 0)
[1] 1 3
```

You could argue that the 2nd element and the 4th element in `df$First` match the previous value (instead of the 1st and 3rd), therefore, `which(c(F, diff(rleid(df$First)) == 0))` might be more appropriate, which yields: `[1] 2 4`